# jQuery.mmenu plugin causing ADA compliance errors

Tags: html, anchor, accessibility, mmenu

We are working on ADA compliance for our site and are using the [Web Accessibility Evaluation Tool](http://wave.webaim.org/) to help identify issues that need to be corrected. We've noticed more than half the errors come from code generated by the [jQuery.mmenu plugin](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/), which we use to generate the navigation for mobile view.

Does anyone know if a fix for ADA compliance issues has been addressed yet by the developer? Here's a link to the report we get when running our site through the Web Accessibility Evaluation Tool:

http://wave.webaim.org/report#/www.woodstockoutlet.com

The errors that are appearing most frequently are links with no text, such as this, which are dynamically created by the mmenu plugin:

```
<a class="mm-btn mm-prev" href="#mm-2" data-target="#mm-2"></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the "screen-reader" add-on, it can (quote)add a "screen reader only" text for anchors that normally don't have text.
http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/addons/screen-reader.html